# How to set context of javascript closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

So I have ValidationHelper.js that contains a closure:

```
console.log(this) //context of the file is FormManager object
(function($) {
    console.log(this) //context of the closure is window
    ...
}(jQuery)
```

How do I set the context of my closure to FormManager object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set the context :

```
(function($) {
    console.log(this) //context of the closure is the outside this
    ...
}).call(this, jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

In line one this not a closure  !

Check this:

```
(function($) {
    console.log(this);
}).call(this, jQuery)
```

Comment: "In line one this not a closure !" - What do you mean?

Comment: I mean console.log(this) //context of the file is FormManager object this in argumant of log isn't valid !